# Calculate the described squared circle

Tags: geometry, area

I need to calculate the described squared circle... with only given the length of the side (a).

[image]

I need to calculate the area of described squared circle. How exactly is it done with only a side given?

Comment: Join the centre to the bottom right corner. By the Pythagorean Theorem, $R^2+R^2=a^2$. So $R^2=\frac{a^2}{2}$ and now we can find area of circle using the familiar formula.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hm.. your answer is similar to John in the answers, but he has one additional Pi and you don't.

Comment: Tha's because I gave you $R^2$, and referred to the "familiar formula" so that you could complete the calculation. The area is $\pi\times \frac{a^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of the side of the square is $a$ then its diagonal is $\sqrt{2}a$, which is also the diameter of the circle.  The radius of the circle is half this:  $a/\sqrt{2}.$  This makes the area of the circle $\pi a^2 / 2.$

Comment: Is it (a * a / 2) * Pi, or the whole (Pi * a * a) / 2?

Comment: @user117293: Yes. :)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by yes? The first or the second one?

Comment: They'll both give the same (correct) answer.

Comment: Oh, right.. I didn't think of that :/ thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the length of the diagonal $2R$ ($2R$ is the length of the diagonal of the square and the circle), then solve for the radius of the circle: $R$: $$a^2 + a^2 = (2R)^2\iff R = \frac{a}{\sqrt 2}$$

Then use the formula for the area of a circle: $A = \pi R^2$.